# Isekai manga where the MC is banned from his team because he’s weak

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I am looking for an isekai where the MC manages the teams, like in providing food and getting armor and even money. It's an isekai world where the MC's team fights monsters but he can't fight actually because he is weak. He gets banned from his team and goes to a village where he get power beyond expectation. I've forgotten the rest of the story but it’s a good manga.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. If someone posts an incorrect answer, please leave a comment on it about what doesn't match. It's a good way to get more details sometimes.

Comment: I also have been looking for this one. What I remember is that he is one of demon king higher up that manage the troops etc and got fired because he is weak. Then he got some power up when living at the village.

Comment: i found it..Kaiko sareta Ankoku Heishi (30-dai) no Slow na Second Life

Answer (score 3):

Could it be [Shin no Nakama ja Nai to Yuusha no Party wo Oidasareta node, Henkyou de Slow Life suru Koto ni Shimashita](https://myanimelist.net/manga/114175/Shin_no_Nakama_ja_Nai_to_Yuusha_no_Party_wo_Oidasareta_node_Henkyou_de_Slow_Life_suru_Koto_ni_Shimashita), aka "I Was Kicked out of the Hero's Party Because I Wasn't a True Companion so I Decided to Have a Slow Life at the Frontier"?

[image: Cover art for Volume 1 of the manga]

> In a fantasy world in which a young girl with the Divine Protection of
> the hero battles against the demon lord. In that world, Red, the elder
> brother of that young girl hero, possessing the Divine Protection of
> "The Guide" which only grants a high initial level, fought in the
> initial party of the hero.
>
> However, with a Divine Protection that only grants a high level but no
> magic nor martial art nor supernatural ability, he gradually could no
> longer keep up with the battle and in the end, a companion, a sage,
> remarked "You are not a true companion" as he snatched all his
> equipment and kicked him out of the party with just a single copper
> sword.
>
> Having his heart completely shattered, Red distanced himself from the
> battle against the demon lord's army despite knowing that the fate of
> the world rests on it, aiming to live an inconspicuous life alone at
> the frontier Zoltan as he earns money to open a herbalist shop by
> utilizing the knowledge he acquired throughout his journey.
>
> Together with the half-elf carpenter living downtown and the princess
> who couldn't become the hero's companion, he aims to live a slow life
> in the frontier of the world governed by a person's inborn Divine
> Protection!

Comment: I suspect that this may be what the OP is looking for, though I don't recall the MC gaining power after going to the village.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read it myself, but the description reminds me of the premise of [Arifureta: From Commonplace to World's Strongest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arifureta:_From_Commonplace_to_World%27s_Strongest)

[image: Cover to the light novel, showing Yue]

> High-schooler Hajime Nagumo is bullied by his classmate for his relationship with the class idol, Kaori. When he and the rest of his class are transported to a fantasy world, all of his classmates get powerful magical abilities, while Hajime only gains the basic alchemical magic to transmute solid materials, a common ability usually found in craftsmen and smiths. During a dungeon raid, he is betrayed by one of his classmates and dropped to the bottom of the dungeon. He survives the fall and creates weapons to escape the dungeon and become stronger. On his journey, he meets with the imprisoned vampire Yue, and later is joined by the bunny-eared Shea, the perverted dragon Tio, and others.

Comment: I don't thin that qualifies as being banned from the team.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, he was an important strategist in the demon army and was an orphan who was taken in by the previous demon lord some years. But since demons and humans use different kinds of magic, he could not use even basic demon magic after years. So, the new council (or whatever) fires him because of that. And when he enters human settlement he founds out that he actually is a human and that there are 5 kinds of magic among which normal humans possess only one type, while he possess not just all of them but with a perfect score in each, which has never been seen in human history.
Yo! after some searching I guess I got this: [*Kaiko sareta Ankoku Heishi (30-dai) no Slow na Second Life*](https://mangadex.org/title/42076/kaiko-sareta-ankoku-heishi-30-dai-no-slow-na-second-life)